# Get function address from a function structure member

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, structure

I'm trying to get function addresses which are hidden behind structures. Unfortunately, the **`void*`** basic C++ conversion doesn't work, so I used **`C++ template`** instead.

**1. Basic** **`void*`** **C++ conversion doesn't work with functions inside structures, why?**

```
void * lpfunction;
lpfunction = scanf; //OK
lpfunction = MessageBoxA; //OK
```

I made a simple structure :

```
struct FOO{

    void PRINT(void){printf("bla bla bla");}

    void SETA(int){} //nothing you can see
    void SETB(int){} //nothing you can see

    int GETA(void){} //nothing you can see
    int GETB(void){} //nothing you can see
};
///////////////////////////////////////////
void *lpFunction = FOO::PRINT;
```

And the compiling error :

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : 
cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall FOO::*)(void)' to 'void *'
```

**2. Is getting function member addresses impossible?**

Then, I made a template function which is able to convert a function member to address. Then I will call it by assembly. It should be something like this:

```
template <class F,void (F::*Function)()>  
void * GetFunctionAddress() {

    union ADDRESS  
    { 
        void (F::*func)();  
        void * lpdata;  
    }address_data;  

    address_data.func = Function;  
    return address_data.lpdata; //Address found!!!  

}
```

And here is the code :

```
int main()
{
    void * address = GetFunctionAddress<FOO,&FOO::PRINT>();

    FOO number;
    number.PRINT(); //Template call
    void * lpdata = &number;
```

```
    __asm mov ecx, lpdata //Attach "number" structure address
    __asm call address //Call FOO::PRINT with assembly using __thiscall
```

```
printf("Done.\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

But, I see it is **extremely specific**. It looks like **LOCK - KEY**, and I have to make a new template for every set of argument types.

Original (OK) :

```
void PRINT(); //void FOO::PRINT();
```

Modify a bit :

```
void PRINT(int); //void FOO::PRINT(int);
```

Immediately with old template code the compiler shows :

```
//void (F::*func)();
//address_data.func = Function;
```

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 
'void (__thiscall FOO::*)(int)' to 'void (__thiscall FOO::*)(void)'
```

**Why?** They are only addresses.

```
69:       address_data.func = Function;
00420328  mov  dword ptr [ebp-4],offset @ILT+2940(FOO::PRINT) (00401b81)
```

...

EDIT3 : I know the better solution :

```
void(NUMBER::*address_PRINT)(void) = FOO::PRINT;
int(NUMBER::*address_GETA)(void) = FOO::GETA;
int(NUMBER::*address_GETB)(void) = FOO::GETB;
void(NUMBER::*address_SETA)(int) = FOO::SETA;
void(NUMBER::*address_SETA)(int) = FOO::SETB;
```

It's much better than **template**. And by the way I want to achieve the goal :

```
<special_definition> lpfunction;
lpfunction = FOO::PRINT; //OK
lpfunction = FOO::GETA; //OK
lpfunction = FOO::GETB; //OK
lpfunction = FOO::SETA; //OK
lpfunction = FOO::SETB; //OK
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not just call the function with the normal method pointer syntax?  (`.*`, `->*`).  Manually setting this `this` pointer and using `call` in inline asm seems like it could become a real headache... (This code only works on the 32-bit MS compiler...)

Comment: Because actually I am making a small interpreter... :D

Comment: A `void *` and a member function pointer aren't even the same size. You can't fit a member function pointer into a `void *`. Your code that uses assembly there works purely by accident.

Comment: @Omnifarious - Pretty sure they are the same size with the MS compiler.  (At least that would be true of COM objects.)  Of course there is nothing in the standard to guarantee they are the same size, and this questioner seems to have thrown the standard out the window.

Comment: Member function pointers are a tricky thing, especially with virtual functions and multiple/virtual inheritance. Their implementation is compiler-dependant and not set in stone. I'll second Omnifarious's recommendation to stop and rethink your design, and give you some further reading: [The C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0201834545/), [Pointers to member functions are very strange animals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx), [A function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).

Comment: I'm amused that you are absolutely determined to beat C++ into being C or assembly, and no amount of anybody telling you that perhaps this is the wrong approach is going to change your mind. _chuckle_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointers to member functions are nothing like pointers to global functions or static member functions. There are many reasons for this, but I'm not sure how much you know about how C++ works, and so I'm not sure what reasons will make sense.

I do know that what you are trying in assembly simply won't work in the general case. It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the purpose of member functions and function pointers.

The thing is, you are doing some things that you would generally not do in C++. You don't generally build up tables of function pointers in C++ because the things you would use that sort of thing for are what `virtual` functions are for.

If you are determined to use this approach, I would suggest you not use C++ at all, and only use C.

To prove these pointer types are completely incompatible, here is a program for you:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
   int addThem() { return a + b; }
};

struct Bar {
   int c;
   int d;
   int addThemAll() { return c + d; }
};

struct Qux : public Foo, public Bar {
   int e;
   int addAllTheThings() { return Foo::addThem() + Bar::addThemAll() + e; }
};

int addThemGlobal(Foo *foo)
{
   return foo->a + foo->b;
}

int main()
{
   int (Qux::*func)();

   func = &Bar::addThemAll;
   printf("sizeof(Foo::addThem) == %u\n", sizeof(&Foo::addThem));
   printf("sizeof(Bar::addThemAll) == %u\n", sizeof(&Bar::addThemAll));
   printf("sizeof(Qux::addAllTheThings) == %u\n", sizeof(&Qux::addAllTheThings));
   printf("sizeof(func) == %u\n", sizeof(func));
   printf("sizeof(addThemGlobal) == %u\n", sizeof(&addThemGlobal));
   printf("sizeof(void *) == %u\n", sizeof(void *));
   return 0;
}
```

On my system this program yields these results:

```
$ /tmp/a.out 
sizeof(Foo::addThem) == 16
sizeof(Bar::addThemAll) == 16
sizeof(Qux::addAllTheThings) == 16
sizeof(func) == 16
sizeof(addThemGlobal) == 8
sizeof(void *) == 8
```

Notice how the member function pointer is 16 bytes long. It won't fit into a `void *`. It isn't a pointer in the normal sense. Your code and `union` work purely by accident.

The reason for this is that a member function pointer often needs extra data stored in it related to fixing up the object pointer it's passed in order to be correct for the function that's called. In my example, when called `Bar::addThemAll` on a `Qux` object (which is perfectly valid because of inheritance) the pointer to the `Qux` object needs to be adjusted to point at the `Bar` sub-object before the function is called. So `Qux::*`s to member functions must have this adjustment encoded in them. After all, saying `func = &Qux::addAllTheThings` is perfectly valid, and if that function were called no pointer adjustment would be necessary. So the pointer adjustment is a part of the function pointer's value.

And that's just an example. Compilers are permitted to implement member function pointers in any way they see fit (within certain constraints). Many compilers (like the GNU C++ compiler on a 64-bit platform like I was using) will implement them in a way that do not permit any member function pointer to be treated as at all equivalent to normal function pointers.

There are ways to deal with this. The swiss-army knife of dealing with member function pointers is the `::std::function` template in C++11 or C++ TR1.

An example:

```
 #include <functional>

 // .... inside main
    ::std::function<int(Qux *)> funcob = func;
```

`funcob` can point at absolutely anything that can be called like a function and needs a `Qux *`. Member functions, global functions, static member functions, functors... `funcob` can point at it.

That example only works on a C++11 compiler though. But if your compiler is reasonably recent, but still not a C++11 compiler, this may work instead:

```
 #include <tr1/functional>

 // .... inside main
    ::std::tr1::function<int(Qux *)> funcob = func;
```

If worse comes to worse, you can use the Boost libraries, which is where this whole concept came from.

But I would rethink your design. I suspect that you will get a lot more milage out of having a well thought out inheritance hierarchy and using `virtual` functions than you will out of whatever it is you're doing now. With an interpreter I would have a top level abstract 'expression' class that is an abstract class for anything that can be evaluated. I would give it a virtual `evaluate` method. Then you can derive classes for different syntax elements like an addition expression a variable or a constant. Each of them will overload the evaluate method for their specific case. Then you can build up expression trees.

Not knowing details though, that's just a vague suggestion about your design.

Comment: +1, and *what* is your rig configuration (its killing me not knowing).

Comment: @WhozCraig: It's a Virtual Box virtual machine running the 64-bit version of Fedora 18 on a Retina display Mac.

Comment: What? My results are always four. (sizeof == 4)

Comment: Lol. ok. and thanks for reminding me I need to install the latest Ubuntu in a VM on my MBAir =P *love* my mac laptop. <3

Comment: @xersi: Well, try compiling and running that code on some different machines. You'll get different answers. Though I'm really surprised that you have a size of 4 for a pointer to a member function.

Comment: @xersi: There, I added some more cases to my program. I suspect you might get answers other than 4 for some of them now.

Comment: All results are four, except the code : "int (Qux::*func)();" It returns 8 (bytes)

Comment: @xersi: `Qux::addAllTheThings` should've been 8 too. I made a small error in the program and I just fixed it. Now you should see 8 twice. I was positive that you would see a different result for `Qux::*` member function pointers because there is absolutely no way for the compiler to implement them in just 4 bytes.

Comment: @manu-fatto - thank you for your solution. But unfortunately, the compiler throws "cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall NUMBER::*)(void)' to 'void *" - WHY???

Comment: @xersi: mannu-fatto's answer **is not** a solution! It's an error and a core dump waiting to happen.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Wow I see. But, what is address??? It is number, or anything else??? - I'm really confused, and as you can see I get successfully function member address using C++ template but the problem is "I have to make hundreds various template objects for hundreds different specific function types..." :(

Comment: @xersi: I will put a couple of solutions to the problem you're trying to solve into this question. But really, you should be solving a different problem. I don't know how your whole program works, but from what you've said so far, I think you should seriously rethink your design.

Comment: @xersi: There, I've added an idea or two for dealing with your problem. An an explanation for what a member function pointer is and why it's not 'just a pointer'.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean solution. By means of a template wrap your member function into a static member function. Then you can convert it to whatever pointer you want:

```
template<class F, void (F::*funct)()>
struct Helper: public T {
  static void static_f(F *obj) {
    ((*obj).*funct)();
  };
};

struct T {
  void f() {
  }
};

int main() {
  void (*ptr)(T*);
  ptr = &(Helper<T,&T::f>::static_f);
}
```

Comment: +1: This works, but is sort of tedious because you have to create a new template for every set of argument types. It at least won't result in undefined behavior when used. :-)

Comment: One could. :-) But that would make it a C++11-only program. :-)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need to convert a pointer to a member function to a void *. I presume you want to give that pointer as a "user data" to some library function and then you will get back your pointer and want to use it on some given object.

If this is the case a `reinterpret_cast<void *>(...)` could be the right thing... I assume that the library receiving the pointer is not using it.

Comment: That won't actually work. A member function pointer doesn't fit into a `void *`.

Comment: My OS is Windows - 32-bit - So an address must be 4 bytes.

Comment: Assembly - A function always is 32-bit number address : http://pastebin.com/6UkX1fq9

Comment: I'm going to -1 this one because it will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Omnifarious > it will result in undefined behavior - actually I absolutely have no idea... [Edit] : I tried C++98 code; the compiler says "Missing file" - Cannot open include file: 'tr1/functional': No such file or directory

Comment: @xersi: Then, if you want to use the `function` template, you'll have to use the Boost library. It's a very good library, and it has its own version of that template that will work with your compiler. I would really suggest getting a newer compiler if you can though.

Comment: Thank you, Omnifarious. I'm going to update my compiler now. But my connection is slow; I'm using my old USB connector... I'm going to explain the problem more clearly and show you the goal... :)